# Smallest Multiple

Tags: c#, performance

I have a code here written in C# that finds the smallest multiple by all numbers from 1 to 20. However, I find it very inefficient since the execution took awhile before producing the correct answer. I would like to know what are the different ways that I can do to improve the code. Thank You.

```
        public static void SmallestMultiple()
    {
        const ushort ARRAY_SIZE = 21;
        ushort[] array = new ushort[ARRAY_SIZE];
        ushort check = 0;
        for (uint value = 1; value < uint.MaxValue; value++)
        {
            for (ushort j = 1; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++)
            {
                array[j] = j;
                if (value % array[j] == 0)
                {   
                    check++;
                }
            }
            if (check == 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The value is {0}", value);
            }
            else
            {
                check = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please accept Blender's or AppDeveloper's answer (whichever you find more useful)? My answer does optimize the program, but I think their approach is the correct one.

Comment: I think your algorithm is fine, but instead of tracking the full list which is less performant on memory just track the var smallest = int.MaxValue; and if it's smaller then update it and return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).ToArray();
        int lcm = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            lcm = LCM(lcm, nums[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("LCM = {0}", lcm);
    }

    public static int LCM(int value1, int value2)
    {
        int a = Math.Abs(value1);
        int b = Math.Abs(value2);

        // perform division first to avoid potential overflow
        a = checked((a / GCD(a, b)));
        return checked((a * b));
    }

    public static int GCD(int value1, int value2)
    {
        int gcd = 1;     // Greates Common Divisor

        // throw exception if any value=0
        if (value1 == 0 || value2 == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        // assign absolute values to local vars
        int a = Math.Abs(value1);            // local var1
        int b = Math.Abs(value2);            // local var2

        // if numbers are equal return the first
        if (a == b) { return a; }
            // if var "b" is GCD return "b"
        if (a > b && a % b == 0) { return b; }
            // if var "a" is GCD return "a"
        if (b > a && b % a == 0) { return a; }

        // Euclid algorithm to find GCD (a,b):
        // estimated maximum iterations: 
        // 5* (number of dec digits in smallest number)
        while (b != 0)
        {
            gcd = b;
            b = a % b;
            a = gcd;
        }
        return gcd;
    }
}
```

---

Source : [Fast Integer Algorithms: Greatest Common Divisor and Least Common Multiple, .NET solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/161824/Fast-Integer-Algorithms-Greatest-Common-Divisor-an)

Answer (score 2):

Since the result must also be divisible by 19 (which is the greatest prime number) up to 20, you might only cycle through multiples of 19.

This should get to to the result about 19 times faster.

Here's the code that does this:

```
public static void SmallestMultiple()
{
    const ushort ARRAY_SIZE = 21;
    ushort[] array = new ushort[ARRAY_SIZE];
    ushort check = 0;

    for (uint value = 19; value < uint.MaxValue; value += 19)
    {
        for (ushort j = 1; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++)
        {
            array[j] = j;
            if (value % array[j] == 0)
            {
                check++;
            }
        }
        if (check == 20)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The value is {0}", value);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            check = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

On my machine, this finds the result `232792560` in a little over 2 seconds.

#### Update

Also, please note that the initial program did not stop when reaching a solution; I have added a `return` statement to make it stop.

Comment: Thank You! Why haven't I thought of that.

Comment: @AppDeveloper sure, I'm not saying it's optimal. The OP asked for *"different ways to improve"* the code's performance. This is one optimization that can be done.

Comment: @w0lf: Why optimize a flawed approach?

Comment: @Blender Initially I thought the question was about optimizing *that* code. However, your approach (and AppDeveloper's) is the right one. I suggested that the OP changes the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're just looking for the [LCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of the numbers from 1 to 20:

[image: formula]

Where the GCD can be efficiently calculated with the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

I don't know C#, but this Python solution shouldn't be hard to translate:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b != 0:
       a, b = b, a % b

    return a

def lcm(a, b):
    return (a * b) / gcd(a, b)

numbers = range(1, 20 + 1)

print reduce(numbers, lcm)
```

It's pretty fast too:

```
>>> %timeit reduce(lcm, range(1, 20000))
1 loops, best of 3: 258 ms per loop
```

Comment: +1 Great solution. I translated it to C# and it can be tested online here: http://ideone.com/mltUzp . However, this yields the correct result when run on the range 1-19, but for numbers 1-20 it yields a smaller (and incorrect) number.

Comment: @w0lf: Must've been a translation error. It works just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** v2.0 - Major speed improvement

Building on w0lf's solution. A faster solution:

```
public static void SmallestMultiple()
{
    // this is a bit quick and dirty
    //   (not too difficult to change to generate primeProduct dynamically for any range)
    int primeProduct = 2*3*5*7*11*13*17*19;
    for (int value = primeProduct; ; value += primeProduct)
    {
       bool success = true;
        for (int j = 11; j < 21; j++)
        {
            if (value % j != 0)
            {
                success = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The value is {0}", value);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You needn't check 1-10 since if something is divisible by x (e.g. 12), it is divisible by x/n (e.g. 12/2 = 6). The smallest multiple will always be a multiple of a product of all the primes involved.

Didn't benchmark C# solution, but equivalent Java solution runs in about 0.0000006 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish here but your out side for loop will run approximately 4,294,967,295 time (uint.MaxValue). So that will take some time...

If you have a way to keep from going to uint.MaxValue - like breaking your loop when you have accomplished what you need to - that will speed it up.

Also, since you are setting array[j] equal to j and then apparently never using the array again why not just do:

```
value % j
```

instead of

```
value % array[j]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using also code written by W0lf (sorry but i cannot comment on your post) I would improve it (only a little) deleting the array that I think is useless..

```
public static void SmallestMultiple()
{
    const ushort ARRAY_SIZE = 21;
    ushort check = 0;
    for (uint value = 1; value < uint.MaxValue; value++)
    {
        for (ushort j = 1; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++)
        {
            if (value % j == 0)
            {   
                check++;
            }
        }
        if (check == 20)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The value is {0}", value);
        }
        else
        {
            check = 0;
        }
    }
}
```